# While finding delta algebraically of quadratic functions, can we proceed in this way?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

while doing it this way, the answer obtained is wrong. Where have I possibly made an error?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when you solve equations with modulus. You didn't get the least upper boundary for $|x+2|$:
$$
0 \leq |x^2| < 4.5 \\
\Updownarrow \\
0 \leq |x| < \sqrt{4.5} \\
\Updownarrow \\
-\sqrt{4.5} < x < \sqrt{4.5} \\
\Updownarrow \\
2-\sqrt{4.5} < x+2 < 2+\sqrt{4.5} \\
\color{red}{\Uparrow} \\
0 \leq |x+2| < |2-\sqrt{4.5}| \text{ and } 0 \leq |x+2| < |2+\sqrt{4.5}| \\
\Updownarrow \\
0 \leq |x+2| < \min(|2-\sqrt{4.5}|, |2+\sqrt{4.5}|) = \sqrt{4.5}-2
$$

Comment: How do you get this : 0≤|x+2|<|2−√4.5|? This statement seems to imply that 2−√4.5 was smaller than x+2 only because it was negative.

Comment: I think that I made a mistake giving a good example of what I wrote myself: "Be careful when you solve equations with modulus." :-o

Comment: However, it depends on in what direction you want the implications to go. $0 \leq |x^2| < 4.5$ implies $0 \leq |x+2| < \max(|2-\sqrt{4.5}|, |2+\sqrt{4.5}|)$ but probably you want the implications the other way around and the you need to take $|x+2| < \min(|2-\sqrt{4.5}|, |2+\sqrt{4.5}|)$ to make $0 \leq |x^2| < 4.5.$

Comment: got it but how is min(|2−√4.5|,|2+√4.5|)=√4.5−2?

Comment: also solving using usual method (delta <= 1) ,| x-2|.|x+2|<0.5, max of |x-2| = -3, |x+2| < 0.5/-3 = -0.166 = delta?

Comment: Because $|2-\sqrt{4.5}| = \sqrt{4.5}-2 < 2+\sqrt{4.5}$.

Comment: oh, my bad. I completely missed that! btw, why is answer different on using delta <=1 method?

Comment: You have made some mistake; you cannot have $\max |x-2| = -3,$ a negative number.

Comment: I added implication and equivalence arrows.